# How to use the load command with MySQL in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql

In MySQL, I can run:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/pt/test/bal.csv" INTO TABLE bal FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '"' IGNORE 1
LINES;
```

However, in my Ruby program:

```
str="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/pt/test/bal.csv" INTO TABLE bal
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES;"

puts str

dbh.query(str)
```

The output is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/pt/test/bal.csv" INTO TABLE bal FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '"' IGNORE 1
LINES;

/home/pt/test/ptb.rb:34:in `query': Field separator argument is not what
is expected; check the manual (Mysql::Error)
from /home/pt/test/ptb.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: str="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"/home/pt/test/bal.csv\" INTO TABLE bal
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\"'
IGNORE 1 LINES;"
Try this it will work..:)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in `ENCLOSED BY ' \"'`

```
str="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"/home/pt/test/bal.csv\" INTO TABLE bal FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"
```

You may also find useful the `%Q[]` [Ruby syntax](https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/). It's analog of `""`, but you don't need to escape `"` inside the string:

```
str=%Q[LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/pt/test/bal.csv" INTO TABLE bal FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;]
```

Comment: Did you try the %Q[] syntax?

Comment: I have done but its not working the main error is: Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual (Mysql::Error) from /home/pt/test/ptb.rb:34:in'

Comment: Can you just copy and paste this code without any changes: dbh.query %Q[LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/pt/test/bal.csv" INTO TABLE bal FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;]

Comment: Done but i end up with the error :
 `query': The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version (Mysql::Error)